# Cómo validar que el total puede tener un margen de diferencia de +- 1 centavo

Tags: php, xml

Estoy en la búsqueda de una solución para permitir la carga de un archivo XML donde el valor denominado `Total` permita una diferencia de 1 centavo por encima o por debajo del valor real, para esta solución obtengo el valor del Total archivo XML de la siguiente manera:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMlElement( $_FILES['XmlToUpload']['tmp_name'], 0, true );
$total = (float)$xml['Total'];
```

Para explicar detalladamente lo que quiero lograr pondré el siguiente ejemplo, al leer el nodo `Total` del archivo XML este obtiene como valor el siguiente `Total= "9840.00"`, lo que quiero permitir al cargar el archivo XML es que permita que ese total aunque tenga una diferencia de más o menos 1 centavo, es decir, que aunque el `Total` del archivo XML tenga un valor de `Total="9839.99"` o `Total="9840.01"` permita cargar el archivo.

El archivo XML se carga de la siguiente manera:

```
$fileXML = $_FILES['XmlToUpload']['name'];
$pathXML = "//LOCATION/XML/";
    
$filepathXML = $pathXML.$fileXML;

if(move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['XmlToUpload']['tmp_name'], $pathXML . $fileXML)){
    echo 'Success Upload File';
}
```

Espero que alguien me pueda dar alguna orientación sobre cómo hacer esta validación.

**Actualización 1:**

Lo que intente para comparar el valor Total si esta dentro de la holgura 1- centavo fue agregar dos variables nuevas, una sumando al total una cantidad de **"0.01"** y la otra variable restar la cantidad de **"0.01"** .

Las variables las declare de la siguiente manera:

```
$totalMgS = $total + "0.01";
$totalMgI = $total - "0.01";
```

Posteriormente me adelante a crear la siguiente validación en la sección de carga de mi archivo XML:

```
if($total <= $totalMgS && $total >= $totalMgI){
    if(move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['XmlToUpload']['tmp_name'], $pathXML . $fileXML)){
        echo 'Esta dentro de la holgura';
    }
}else{
    echo "No esta dentro de la holgura";
}
```

Cuando intento cargar un archivo XML donde `$total` tiene una diferencia de 0.01, el archivo no se carga y me lanza el mensaje de "No esta dentro de la holgura"

¿Hay algún cambio que deba hacer en mi validación?

**Actualización 2**

Retomando nuevamente el tema y ya para darle validez, estuve analizando todo este tiempo de que tengo que comparar el total con otro, y efectivamente ahora lo visualizo así, ese otro numero con el que debo compararlo se encuentra almacenado en una tabla de base de datos el cual estoy mostrando en una etiqueta en HTML de la siguiente manera:

```
<div class="form-group row" >
    <label for="lblName" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Total:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="text" name="txtTotal" class="form-control" id="txtTotal" disabled>
    </div>
</div>
```

Después declaro en mi Javascript la variable:

```
var TotalTable = $("#txtTotal").val();
```

Después la agrego a mi data para luego ser llamada desde PHP.

```
datosForm.append("TotalTable", $("#txTotal").val());
```

Y por ultimo la llamo desde PHP.

```
$TotalReal = (isset($_POST["TotalTable"]));
```

He llamado a mi variable en PHP como `$TotalReal`

Para validar que el total sea el mismo que tengo en mi etiqueta en HTML y que sea el mismo que tengo almacena en base de datos, mando a imprimir la variable `$TotalReal` pero esto solamente me devuelve 1.

La estoy imprimiendo de la siguiente manera:

```
echo $TotalReal;
```

Hay algo que deba cambiar en como estoy obteniendo de la variable desde Javascript? O debo hacer alguna conversión a tipo de dato `float`?

**Actualización 3:**

Para asignar el valor al input lo hago desde una función en Javascript de la siguiente manera:

```
function CargarArchivo (Total){    
    $("#txtTotal").val(Total);
}
```

**Actualización 4:**

He adaptado mi código a una respuesta, pero al tratar de imprimir el resultado de mi variable es `undefined`

```
$totalreal = (isset($_POST['TotalTable']));

if(isset($_POST['TotalTable']) ) {
    $totalreal = $_POST['TotalTable'];
  } else {
    // No se recibió ningún valor en el input 'TotalTable'
  }

$margen = "0.01";

echo $totalreal;

if($total >= $totalreal - $margen && $total <= $totalreal + $margen){// Está dentro del margen
} else {
    // No está dentro del margen
}
```

Como pueden visualizar estoy imprimiendo antes, solo para fines de prueba el `$totalreal`, pero esto me devuelve una variable `undefined`

**Actualización 5:**

He corregido el problema de la variable undefined, esto se debía que la variable que estaba colocando en el data no existía, esto fue por que me hacía falta una letra en el nombre de la variable, ya quedo corregido.

Ahora el problema que estoy teniendo es que el archivo XML que estoy cargando tiene la diferencia de 1 centavo contra el `$totalreal` y aun así el error que me indica es que no esta dentro del margen.

Por si sirve de algo agrego el archivo XML que estoy cargando y el cual contiene el nodo que es que el quiero comparar.

```
<cfdi:Voucher xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
Certificated="m4gfzi9yNXuC0A=" 
Condition="002" 
Date="2021-06-29T16:02:16" 
Number="4938" 
Payment="23" 
NoCertificated="404627114" 
Total="9840.00" 
Version="3.3">
</cfdi:Voucher>
```

Es importante dejar claro que ese $total ya lo estoy leyendo desde el archivo XML de la siguiente manera:

```
$total = (float)$xml['Total'];
```

Hay alguna modificación que deba hacer en la validación ?

Comment: Si el nodo `Total` trae una cifra específica ¿contra qué valor lo vas a comparar para saber si está dentro de la *holgura* de +- 1 centavo?

Comment: @MauricioContreras te debo la soda... es lo mismo que estaba escribiendo yo XD

Comment: @MauricioContreras Una disculpa, agregue una actualización a mi pregunta en donde creo que puedo compararlo con el nodo `Total`

Comment: esa dos variables no tienen sentido si sumas o resta 1 centavo siempre tendran 1 centavo de diferencia... esas validaciones requiere que hagas la suma de paridad, que vendria a realizar nuevamente dentro del php la suma de los elementos que te interesan cuadre y validar el calculo hecho en php vs el valor recivido en el xml

Comment: la otra forma es, si tienes el total o los elementos en una base de datos consultarlos y compararlos contra el xml...

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Los elementos no los tengo almacenados en base de datos para compararlos, ¿a que te refieres con suma de paridad? podrías aportarme por favor un ejemplo en base a mi pregunta para darle validez

Comment: perdon.. pero le estas sumando a un numero un string??? $total + "0.01"; esto funciona y da un numero??? o da un string??? podrias mandar a imprimir total y totalMgS y totalMgI.. son strings o numeros??? lo que estas haciendo es correcto.. pero el como, suena raro...

Comment: @gbianchi esto es PHP, todo es raro

Comment: @gbianchi no esta nada de bien lo que hace; sumarle/restarle un centavo para luego validar que hay 1 centavo diferencia, es como llegar y cortarle un brazo a una persona para despues validar que le falta el brazo...

Comment: no.. se hace asi.. esta perfecto... como esperas validar si el numero esta dentro del rango para cuando trabajas con centavos????

Comment: @gbianchi Pensé que la validación que había realizado era la correcta, alguna orientación en como realizarlo correctamente ?

Comment: Pensemos un rato en esto: `$total` se obtiene del XML, luego calculo el valor superior e inferior basado en `$total`, por último valido que `$total` se encuentra en el rango que ¡¡¡calculé en base a `$total`!!!

Comment: @MauricioContreras tenes razon.. maldicion.. jajajajaj...

Comment: igual lo gracioso es que eso le da falso.. es peor de lo que parece...

Comment: Le da falso porque tal como comentas suma cadenas con valores numéricos y a saber lo que termina comparando. XD

Comment: VAMOS DE VUELTA (mayusculas a proposito)... te da mal, porque sumas cadenas y numeros y no sabemos que queda ahi. Luego, el total tiene que ser un centavo mas o menos de que? de si mismo? eso siempre va a dar positivo.. deberia ser un centavo mas o menos de otro numero.. si no, esta pregunta no tiene sentido..

Comment: No tengo otro numero, el único numero que obtengo es el `$total` que estoy obteniendo leyendo de mi archivo XML

Comment: y entonces.. total siempre va a ser menor que total +1 y mayor que total -1.. esta pregunta, no tiene sentido...

Comment: Posiblemente lo que no tenga sentido es lo que agregue en mi actualización 1, ya comprendí el error en la validación que agregue, esto es para mostrar lo que he realizado hasta ahora, pero la pregunta como tal si tiene sentido

Comment: @gbianchi Comprendo lo de no sumar cadenas y números, debo convertir la cadena a numero para que mi validación sea correcta ?

Comment: @JohnDoe si, pero igual, TU VALIDACION NO TIENE SENTIDO

Comment: `$_POST["TotalTable"]`. Dónde está el `<input ... name="TotalTable">` en tu formulario? ¿O es que estoy ciego y no lo veo?

Comment: @Dreyf el `input` lo tengo de la siguiente manera: `<input type="text" name="txtTotal" class="form-control" id="txtTotal" disabled>`  si te fijas estoy usando el id de ese input para declararlo en Javascript, el `input` lo agregue en el primer fragmento de código de tercera actualización, estoy haciendo algo mal ?

Comment: @JohnDoe ¿Y por qué está `disabled`? ¿Es para que no se muestre? ¿No es mejor usar un input hidden para eso? `<input type="hidden" name="txtTotal" class="form-control" id="txtTotal">`

Comment: @Dreyf De acuerdo, usare `hidden` para ocultarlo, solo lo había puesto `disabled` para fines de pruebas, alguna otra recomendación ? Lo cambie a `hidden` pero aun me devuelve el valor 1

Comment: @JohnDoe Lo que no entiendo es dónde ponés el valor (`value`) del input. Podrías poner el código donde asignás el valor para saber porqué está enviando un 1.

Comment: @JohnDoe Okey. Lo acabo de ver. Es que ando ciego. Podrías poner todo el código donde envías los datos. El problema veo que está al asignarle el valor y por eso te pone un 1. Si ponés todo el código podría tener algo más de contexto para ayudarte.

Comment: @Dreyf He agregado una actualización en donde explico como estoy asignando el valor al `input`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138492/discussion-between-john-doe-and-dreyf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para validar el margen de diferencia, como te dijeron en los comentarios, necesitás algo con lo que comparar.

Ese algo por lo que veo en tu código es la siguiente línea:

```php
$TotalReal = (isset($_POST["TotalTable"]));
```

El cual, según comentás, te devuelve un `1`. Esto es debido a que estás asignando en `$TotalReal` el valor devuelto por la función [isset](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset). Y esta devuelve **true** en caso de que la variable pasada por argumento exista. Esa variable existe por eso te retorna un valor booleano que luego se traduce como **1**.

Tu código debería quedar así:

```php
if( isset($_POST['TotalTable']) ) {
    $TotalReal = $_POST['TotalTable'];
} else {
    // No se recibió ningún valor en el input 'TotalTable'
}
```

Una vez arreglado eso ahora sí podrías hacer las comparaciones.

Suponiendo que la variable `$total` contiene el total a comparar y la variable `$TotalReal` es con la cual vas a medir el margen de diferencia: vamos a agregar una variable más que va a ser el margen: `$margen = '0.01'`.

```php
$TotalReal = "9840.00";
$total = "9839.99"; // El valor a comparar
$margen = "0.01"; // 1 centavo

if( $total >= $TotalReal - $margen && $total <= $TotalReal + $margen ) {
    // Está dentro del margen
} else {
    // No está dentro del margen
}
```

Comment: Intente lo que comentas pero estoy obteniendo la variable `undefined`, algo que deba cambiar en el código ?

Comment: @JohnDoe podrías poner todo el mensaje de error? Si te pone eso es que estás usando las variables que puse como ejemplo. Deberías adaptarlo a tu código.

Comment: He agregado el código a una nueva actualización tal como me indicaste, pero aun así obtengo la variable `undefined`

Answer (score 3):

Buen día,

**Nota:** Para hacer la respuesta un poco más breve estoy suponiendo que ya arreglaste todos los problemas adicionales que pusiste en tu pregunta y puedes leer el valor tanto del `XML` como el del valor que será la referencia y el valor del margen (En caso de que se pueda configurar desde alguna parte) y me enfocaré directamente en la parte de la validación que es la pregunta original.

Este es un problema común al comparar números reales (Y se presenta en cualquier lenguaje de programación).

### Contexto

De la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.float.php) oficial de `php` leemos el siguiente extracto:

> **Advertencia:**
>
> Precisión del punto flotante:
>
> Los números de punto flotante tienen una precisión limitada. Aunque
> depende del sistema, PHP típicamente utiliza el formato de doble
> precisión IEEE 754, el cual dará un error relativo máximo por
> aproximación del orden de 1.11e-16. Las operaciones aritméticas
> elementales no podrán generar grandes errores y, por supuesto, se han
> de considerar los errores por propagación al componer varias
> operaciones.

### Aplicado a tu código

Primero hay que convertir los números de `string` a `float`, para eso puedes utilizar [`floatval()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.floatval.php). Simulando el valor que cargas desde el `XML` con la variable `$xml`:

```
# Valor del XML
$xml = "9840.01";

#Convertir a flotante
$total = floatval($xml);
```

Luego vamos a comparar los valores, la misma documentación (Puse el enlace arriba) muestra un método para compararlo que vamos a adaptar:

Ejemplo de la documentación:

```
$a = 1.23456789;
$b = 1.23456780;
$épsilon = 0.00001;

if(abs($a-$b) < $épsilon) {
    echo "true";
}
```

Adaptación al ejemplo genérico de esta respuesta:

```
# Valor del XML
$xml = "9840.01";

# Convertir a flotante
$total = floatval($xml);

$referencia = 9840.0;
$margen = 0.01;

if (abs($total-$referencia) <= $margen) {
    echo 'carga';
}
else {
    echo 'no carga';
}
```

Si únicamente ejecutamos el programa tal cual vamos a ver que la respuesta es `"no carga"` a pesar de que el valor de `$total` y `$referencia` están aparentemente adentro del margen que establecimos (Los resultados pueden variar según el sistema operativo, tal como explica la documentación).

Si agregamos una línea (Puede ser un simple `printf`) para saber el valor de `abs($total - $referencia)` vamos a ver lo siguiente:

```
# Valor del XML
$xml = "9840.01";

# Convertir a flotante
$total = floatval($xml);

$referencia = 9840.0;
$margen = 0.01;

printf(abs($total-$referencia)."\n");

if (abs($total-$referencia) <= $margen) {
    echo 'carga';
}
else {
    echo 'no carga';
}
```

Resultado:

```
0.010000000000218
no carga
```

Todos esos decimales adicionales vienen de la "precisión limitada" mencionada en la documentación, por lo que la forma correcta de hacerlo sería redondeando para limitar la comparación a dos decimales.

**Nota:** Al redondear puedes utilizar [`round()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.round.php), [`floor()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.floor.php) o [`ceil()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.ceil.php) según te convenga, por favor revisa la documentación para saber la diferencia entre estas funciones. Para el ejemplo voy a utilizar `round()`.

Aplicando el redondeo al código nos queda de la siguiente forma:

```
# Valor del XML
$xml = "9840.01";

# Convertir a flotante
$total = floatval($xml);

$referencia = 9840.0;
$margen = 0.01;

printf(round(abs($total-$referencia),2)."\n");

if (round(abs($total-$referencia),2) <= $margen) {
    echo 'carga';
}
else {
    echo 'no carga';
}
```

Que devuelve:

```
0.01
carga
```

Answer (score 0):

Quizás necesitas que el valor a comparar este definido con un nombre distinto al de referencia?

```
$totalreferencia= floatval("9822.3");
$totalMgS = $totalreferencia + 0.01;
$totalMgI = $totalreferencia - 0.01;

$totalaevaluar = floatval("9822.32");


if(($totalaevaluar<= $totalMgS)&&($totalaevaluar>= $totalMgI)){
'Esta dentro de la holgura'; 
}else{
'No esta dentro de la holgura';
}
```

Comment: Es por aca, pero nos tiene que decir OP cuales son los campos.

Comment: @gbianchi Ya tengo un poco mas definido la pregunta, ahora tengo un valor en base de datos con el que debo comparar, pero aun sigo presentando algunos errores, posiblemente sean mínimos, he agregado una actualización explicando cada detalle